# Implicitly cast parameter to bool

Tags: c++, casting

**Premise:**
I am trying to make a Define scope that is not implemented using a macro because of the potential issues with macros. Here is my initial attempt

```
//version for if not defined
bool Defined()
{
    return false
}

//version for if defined
bool Defined(bool anything)
{
    return true;
}
```

And an example use case

```
if(Defined(_DEBUG))
{
    Stuff...
}
```

which would replace

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    Stuff...
#endif
```

or

```
#define Defined()         false
#define Defined(Anything) true
```

**Benefits:**
syntax is cleaner, it is scoped, 

This code is not conditional, so the compiler will be able to easily optimize code sections out.
**Issues**
There are a few issues with this procedure, the first is the reason for this post.

**Question:**
You can't pass in anything that is not implicitly cast-able to a bool. Is there a way to implicitly cast any object, number, pointer, etc to a bool? I don't believe there is, but I wanted to make sure, before I continued.

Comment: What would it mean to cast, lets say a `Car`, into a `bool`?

Comment: Only the preprocessor knows if `DEBUG` was `#defined` or not.

Comment: @NathanOliver It doesn't matter for what I am doing since I am not using the result, but I guess that would be important for the conversion.

Comment: When `DEBUG` is not defined, the token `DEBUG` expands to `DEBUG`, not to nothing

Comment: I don't understand why you would want this. `if` blocks and `#ifdef` blocks usually serves very different purpose.

Comment: @super #ifdef blocks can be very ugly in the middle of code sometimes. I was trying to find a better syntax, and the "if" block is extremely easy to interpret.

Comment: There is no such thing as an implicit cast. You're talking about an implicit **conversion**. A cast is always explicit. It's something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Comment: You may be better off with a `#ifdef DEBUG using is_debug = std::true_type; #else using is_debug = std::false_type; #endif` or a `#ifdef DEBUG constexpr auto is_debug = true; #else constexpr auto is_debug = false; #endif`.

Comment: Re: not conditional makes it easier for the compiler to optimize code -- on the contrary, not having the code **at all** makes it easier for the compiler to optimize it. But it sounds like you're reinventing [constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if).

Comment: Please just ask a question, don't try to convince people that it's right.  You end up with a lot of opinions instead of actual answers.

Comment: @Justin yep, somehow I missed that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a generic template:

```
template<class T>
bool Defined(T &&) { return true; }
```

Comment: `t` can be dropped to get rid of the 'unused parameter' warning.

Comment: Though this answers the literal question being asked, beware that it won't achieve the ultimate goal. If `DEBUG` is defined, it likely defined to be empty, which would call `Derived()`. And if it's not defined, `Defined(DEBUG)` uses a presumably undefined identifier `DEBUG`.